# How to force SASL on all Zookeeper connections

Tags: ruby, apache-zookeeper, sasl

I have a recent zookeeper build (version=3.4.3-1240972, built on 02/06/2012 10:48 GMT), and am having trouble forcing SASL to be used on all client connections.

Using the local conf/ directory of the release, I have the following configuration (running on Ubuntu 12.04):

**conf/zoo.cfg**

```
tickTime=2001
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
```

**conf/jaas.conf**

```
Server {
    org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
    user_super="1adminsecret";
};
Client {
    org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
    username="super"
    password="1adminsecret";
};
```

**conf/java.env**

```
export JVMFLAGS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=`pwd`/conf/jaas.conf"
```

When I connect from the zkCli.sh script, it will auth properly, and changing the jaas.conf file will cause it to not be able to query. This is expected behavior.

However, when I use the ruby "zookeeper" gem, and run (with irb):

```ruby
require 'zookeeper'
z = Zookeeper.new("localhost:2181")
z.get_children(:path => "/")
z.create(path:'/asdf', data:'test')
```

it returns results properly. If I'm requiring SASL for login, how come the ruby client is bypassing security. I know it isn't just a read vs. write issue, as I can also create keys as well.

Comment: For reference, I used the following sources for configuring SASL: https://github.com/ekoontz/zookeeper/wiki  and  https://cwiki.apache.org/ZOOKEEPER/zookeeper-and-sasl.html

Comment: you have created a java.env file, how do you read that file from zkCli.sh?

Answer (score 3):

In conf/zoo.cfg, add the line,

```
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
```

From the Server Configuration section [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/ZOOKEEPER/zookeeper-and-sasl.html),

> requireClientAuthScheme=sasl is optional: if it is set to any value,
>   it will only allow non-authenticated clients to ping, create session,
>   close session, or sasl-authenticate.

Comment: I added that line, and it's still allowing everything thru. And I did shutdown the zkServer before changing the config.

Comment: what happens if you add this to your zoo.cfg   maintain_connection_despite_sasl_failure=false

Comment: I've added it there, as well as to the command line (-Dzookeeper. ....), and no luck. Grepping the source code for "maintain_connection", and "requireClientAuthScheme" returns nothing, so where are these params even defined? I've tried both 3.4.3, and 3.3.5, with no luck!

Comment: try setting the system property zookeeper.allowSaslFailedClients=false  on the server.  This is the patch that was committed to add sasl  https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12490160/ZOOKEEPER-938.patch

Comment: @sbridges Broken link.

Comment: @sbridges this is actually not truth. Reading through code you can see that `requireClientAuthScheme=sasl` is not even read if you put it in configuration. There is even jira ticket for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-2668.
FYI I'm as well trying to find a way how to forbid ticketless (kerberos) connections so any advice would help

Comment: It seems the situation has changed. FYI https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1634 - added in 3.6.0, July 24th, 2019. Commit https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/pull/118/files#diff-81e40b9605f507a4c123d55005fc6dc6R1387

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and solved it by adding JVM arguments to the env file. (ZooKeeper 3.6.3)

```
export JVMFLAGS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=`pwd`/conf/jaas.conf \
-Dzookeeper.authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider \
-Dzookeeper.allowSaslFailedClients=false \
-Dzookeeper.sessionRequireClientSASLAuth=true \
"
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you, @user2888962, it helped to me with version 3.8.2

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem years later haha. I hope Zookeeper 3.5 adds a separate and less tricky way to secure a Zookeeper server. Check out my question: [Securing Zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106117/securing-zookeeper-where-to-start/32273336#32273336)